Inequality between $f$-divergences and Fisher information
I am wondering if there exists a general global inequality between some $f$-divergence and Fisher information of the form:
$$\forall \theta_0, \theta_1 ~ D_f(p_{\theta_0} || p_{\theta_1}) \leq C (\theta_1 - \theta_0)^T I(\theta_0) (\theta_1 - \theta_0).$$
I know about the local link between $f$-divergences and Fisher information but here what I am looking for is really a global connection.
This question came to my mind after reading:

@MISC {302116,
TITLE = {Using Fisher Information to bound KL divergence},
AUTHOR = {Gabe K (https://mathoverflow.net/users/125275/gabe-k)},
HOWPUBLISHED = {MathOverflow},
NOTE = {URL:https://mathoverflow.net/q/302116 (version: 2018-06-05)},
EPRINT = {https://mathoverflow.net/q/302116},
URL = {https://mathoverflow.net/q/302116}
},

where it is claimed that such an inequality holds for the Kullback-Leibler divergence.
I am not sure the proof remains correct in the parametric case and I am also interested in a generalization for other $f$-divergences so I created a new post.
There might be a link with log-Sobolev inequalities but again, I am not sure the arguments apply in the parametric case. For example in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1608.05431, there is such an inequality in page 2 but it applies for the Fisher information functional and for Gaussian measures apparently.
